# tilde in hyperref url with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Tags: symbols, tilde

By default, LaTeX typesets tildes "too high", but the hyperref package ordinarily corrects this behaviour for URLs (it vertically centers tildes, as expected). However `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` seems to break this, and the tilde is "too high" again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws}
\end{document}
```

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

before

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

It will work as you expect.
(see [Correctly typesetting a tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312))

Answer (score 18):

Package `hyperref` only uses package `url`. There the tilde can be changed via option `lowtilde`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lowtilde]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Also a tilde from a different font can be used. The following example takes the tilde from Times Roman (ghostscript's clone), e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\UrlTildeSpecial}{%
  \do\~{%
    \mbox{%
      \fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
      \textasciitilde
    }%
  }%  
}%    
\let\Url@force@Tilde\UrlTildeSpecial
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\url{http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result ptm]