# How can I use < and > in \keys{} of menukeys?

Tags: menukeys

For the sake of this question I have created the following small example to reproduce the issue I am asking about.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\keys{a} \keys{b}\\
\keys{A} \keys{B}\\
\keys{<} \keys{>}
\end{document}
```

I would like to synthesize the `<` and `>` character as a key press using `\keys{}`. However, I am **not** talking about **the cursor keys** here. I mean the **smaller than** and **greater than** keys which can be accessed by using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> sequence on a US-English keyboard.

The above example produces this:

[image: erratic menukeys behavior]

**Edit:** I'd like to add the `~` key to the list of problematic characters which won't render inside `\keys{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\keys{a} \keys{b}\\
\keys{A} \keys{B}\\
\keys{<} \keys{>}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, that covers `<` and `>` quite nicely. Any idea for `~`?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde

Answer (score 1):

To add the ~, you can try to create your own tilde and use it inside \keys.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\til}{{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle{\sim}$}}}

\begin{document}
\keys{\til} \keys{\til}
\end{document}
```