# Tilde symbol inside an environment

Tags: environments, matlab, tilde

I have set a new `matcode` environment in order to have some `matlab` code in my .tex file, using the `matlab-prettifier` package (combined with the `listings` package). However, I have a problem with the `tilde` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
% Avoid the spurious error
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\originalTeX\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\@tempcnta\number253\expandafter\relax\originalTeX}%
}
% apply the fix
\addto\extrasgreek{%
    \@tempcnta=128
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta<253\do{%
        \expandafter\babel@savevariable\expandafter{\expandafter\lccode\the\@tempcnta}%
        \lccode\@tempcnta=\@tempcnta
        \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
    }%
}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

 \lstnewenvironment{matcode}
    {
    \selectlanguage{english} 
    \fontfamily{cmr} \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
    \lstset{
     language=matlab-pretty,
                style=Matlab-editor,
                basicstyle = \ttfamily,
                keepspaces=true,
                escapechar=\#}
    }
    {
    \normalsize
    \selectlanguage{greek}
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{matcode}
    % This is a comment.
    [~, a ] 
    \end{matcode}

    \end{document}
```

If I use the `kerkis.sty` package, then the result is going to be this one, where I miss the `tilde` symbol (apparently the `tilde` symbol is not supported by `kerkis`):
[image]

Ignoring (by commenting) the `kerkis.sty` package, the result is going to be this one:
[image]

Although the `tilde` symbol is somewhat displaced, at least it is visible. As you can see, I tried to load the `cmr` font inside the `matcode` environment, but I had no luck with that. So my question is:

> How can I load the `cmr` font inside my `matcode` environment, without commenting the command `\usepackage{kerkis}`?

**Edit:** In order to override this problem and make the `tilde` symbol appear, I used the `escapechar #` and I replaced the `tilde` symbol in my .tex file, with the command `#\texttildelow#`, but this is not a neat solution for sure.

Comment: The tilde character is problematic in many fonts. This is a well-known problem (see section 9, *Tips and tricks*, of the [`matlab-prettifier` manual](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/matlab-prettifier/matlab-prettifier.pdf)). For some solutions, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde.