# Is this a tilde?

Tags: tilde

Is this a tilde or some other ("upper tilde") symbol?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is a tilde. Probably the position depends on your font.

Comment: On my keyboard, I can write both `˜` and `~`.

Comment: @hpekristiansen How you write ˜?

Comment: I press shift and the key left of `!1` on an american apple keyboard the key with `~`. The key is active, so if I type `a` it becomes `ã`, but if I press right arrow, I get `˜`.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I didn't understand, but I read that it's called "small tilde" and on Windows you get it by pressing `ALT` and then the "ALT keycode" 0152 on the numpad. Then release ALT and you get ˜.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same character as Tilde ~. Rather ˜ is called "small tilde" and on Windows one gets it by holding `ALT` then typing the "ALT keycode" **0152** and then releasing the `ALT` key.

In LaTeX one processes it in the following way:

[image]

as given here: [Correctly typesetting a tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde)

Comment: Where is the screenshot from?

Comment: rather than just copying an answer it is better to vote the question as duplicate.

Comment: Is this an answer or additional info to add to your question?