# How to display a 'not tilde' character

Tags: tilde, textcomp

This doesn't seem to work:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand{\TextTilde}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\texttildelow}}

f(n) \not\TextTidle g(n)
```

It displays the slash before the tilde. Is there any way I can get it to appear over the tilde?

This is where I learned how to make a tilde: [Correctly typesetting a tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde/377#377)

Comment: There is an error in your text, maybe it's because of this: you have written `\not\TextTidle`, whereas it should have been `\not\TextTilde`.

Comment: Why do you want to typeset a "tilde" character into text which seems to belong into a math environment? $f(n) \not\sim g(n)$?

Comment: @genericFJS - You should post an answer featuring `\not\sim`.

Answer (score 5):

Since it seems that you want to use the "tilde" in a mathematical context, the character `\sim` (for similar) would make more sense:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$f(n) \not\sim g(n)$
\end{document}
```

In that context, there is no need to typeset the "tilde" character as text.

Comment: ...or with `amssymb` you can use `\nsim`