# Why ~ is not shown in place in R source listings?

Tags: r, sourcecode

My sample code is-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},language=R]{code.R}
\end{document}
```

and `code.R` is -

```
m.datF <- read.csv("modified_dataF.csv", header=T)[,-1]
mod <- glm(salary ~ ., family=gaussian,  data=m.datF)
summary(mod)
```

output shows -
[image]

In this output the `~` is positioned little up.

Comment: That is font dependent...

Comment: @TeXnician then what can I do?

Comment: Change the font. Personally I do not know which font fixes this, but I'll post a fix.

Comment: I don't know why people are asking to close currently as no duplicate invoking the `listings` context has been put forward so far.

Comment: @jfbu See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130513/124577) to the question which is linked now.

Comment: @TeXnician yes that's true. But 1) that answer over there is not an answer to the question over there, but to the one here, 2) it is not the same as the one you provided. As a result the mechanism of the site simply does not work. If someone comes with a better answer to the specific listinsg context, he has no place where to put it. If someone has the same question as here he has to identify which one of the 8 overthere applies. Does not look efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `literate` feature to fix the tilde positioning (or compile your current code with `lualatex` that apparently fixes it too).

[image: tilde]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,literate={~}{{\raisebox{-3pt}{\textasciitilde}}}1}
\begin{lstlisting}
~test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```