# Quotation marks and hyphen in listings generate un-copyable PDF

Tags: formatting, listings, copy-paste

I'm writing a document for general purpose so that anyone can follow it and the idea is to copy and paste this command in a Linux terminal. But when I do that in a terminal give me error because quotation marks are displayed like this `”` instead of `"` and hyphens are rendered as an en-dash `−` (a large dash) instead of this `-`.

What I achieved:

```
\lstdefinestyle{BashInputStyle}{
  language=bash,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=3pt,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},
  linewidth=0.9\linewidth,
  xleftmargin=0.1\linewidth
}
```

For example this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=BashInputStyle]
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
\end{lstlisting}
```

produces this PDF output:

[image]

and the text copied from the PDF is:

```
sh −c ”$(curl −fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh−my−zsh/master/tools/install.sh)”
```

but it should be like this:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `literate` key you can change the definition of the characters. To make the upright quotation marks I `literate`d the `"` and `'` symbols to be replaced by `\textquotedbl` and `\textquotesingle`, from the `textcomp` package (you have to use the `T1` encoding for `\textquotedbl`). For the `-` it was enough to add it to the list.

The tilde is a little bit trickier. To make the copy-pasting correct you just need to load `textcomp` and use `\texttildelow`, but then it looks weird. I found a hint in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160898/134574), by locally changing the font to `ptm` (Times).

The PDF output:

> [image]

and the text copied from the PDF:

```bash
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
cd '~/test/awesome-fontconfig'
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\uprightquote{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\textquotedbl}}
\newcommand\centeredtilde{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\texttildelow}}% From this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160898/134574

\lstdefinestyle{BashInputStyle}{
  language=bash,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=3pt,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},
  linewidth=0.9\linewidth,
  xleftmargin=0.1\linewidth,
  literate =
    {"}{{\uprightquote}}1
    {'}{{\textquotesingle}}1
    {-}{{-}}1
    {~}{{\centeredtilde}}1
    ,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=BashInputStyle]
    $ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
    cd '~/test/awesome-fontconfig'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just one thing and is almost done what about this character the place where linux user's live -> ~ <- I get an stranger character in linux console, when i copy it... regards.,

Comment: @hhlp I added the `~` to the answer ;)

Comment: I also have problem with this character -> 'awesome-fontconfig' <-  when i copy paste is -> ’awesome-fontconfig’  <- ... regards.,

Comment: @hhlp Done. I applied the same principle from the double quotation mark.