# Question on writing symbols (~, tilde)

Tags: overleaf, statistics

I was wondering if anyone can show me how to write `~` in Latex as I am new to Latex and trying to write my statistics notes in a neat format. I've surfed around the web, but could not find it.

Comment: For figuring out how to write a symbol, http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is extremely useful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Next time, you can check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:LaTeX_symbols for example.
- `~` can be written using `\sim` (in math mode) or `\texttildelow` (in text mode, `\usepackage{textcomp}`). The "normal way" `\textasciitilde` still seems to give a strange output.
- I found another example: `\raisebox{-0.9ex}{\~{}}`, see [here](https://praxistipps.chip.de/latex-tilde-im-text-schreiben-so-gehts_92612) (German).
- For more information, see **(1)** [Correctly typesetting a tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312), **(2)** [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363), **(3)** https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=8385 (German), and/or **(4)** https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive.

---

Reaction on the comment of user [chsk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/158639/) ("Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "\textasciitilde still seems to give a strange output"? –").

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\textbackslash textasciitilde}: Text \textasciitilde{} Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Kuehner Thank you :D

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "`\textasciitilde` still seems to give a strange output"?

Comment: @chsk: See update :).

Comment: Thanks --- how's that strange, though? This is how a tilde traditionally was rendered on both typewriters and (later) computers, and very likely this is what not just DEK but anyone who used TeX expected to see when TeX was made.

Comment: @chsk Then replace "strange" with "too high IMHO" :). In my experience, which is limited, people nowadays expect something closer to `\sim`. Feel free to edit my question if you think that it needs modification. This way just a thoughtless comment from me.

Comment: Fair enough. The times, they are a-changin'!