# How can I combine superscript, math symbols together? For instance, Trex1−/−

Tags: math-mode, symbols, superscripts

I was using this command to have my output "*Trex1*−/−", where -/- will be in a superscript and TREX emphasized/italic.
My command is `\emph{Trex1} $^${\num{-}}$/$ $^${\num{-}}`
I get error message saying," undefined control sequence" and "missing { inserted"-what does this mean and how can I solve this? I noticed, even though overleaf makes the output fine, but any text following this symbol becomes italic and skips the margin and alignment.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you desire, but to get "-/-" as a subsript you can use `\emph{Trex1}${}^{-/-}$`. What is `\num{-}` supposed to be?

Comment: I used \num{-} to add the minus sign, isn't it how we add mathematical symbols like plus or minus?

Comment: For a minus sign, just use `-` in math mode. That will have the proper spacing based on if it is a unary negtive `$-5$` or a binary operator `$7-5$.`

Comment: This makes sense, many thanks! but what about these symbols without a number before or after these (+,-. ~)?

Comment: For the tilde see [Correctly typesetting a tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312/4301). The `+` and `-` can just be used directly in math mode. If you want to enforce unary spacing on those you can use `{-}` and `{+}`.

Comment: don't use `$` around every symbol, use it around entire expressions, and don't use `\emph` for mathematics, it is for emphasis in text, It isn't clear what you want `\num` to do (and it isnt defined by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `$^{-/-}$`, because you want a single superscript, albeit composed of multiple characters.

But you possibly don't want math mode at all: `\textsuperscript` is your friend. Anyway, here are four proposals, take your pick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\trex}{\textit{Trex1}\textsuperscript{--/--}}

\newcommand{\trexA}{%
  \textit{Trex1}%
  \textsuperscript{--\negthinspace/\negthinspace--}%
}

\newcommand{\trexM}{\textit{Trex1}$^{-/-}$}

\newcommand{\trexMM}{\textit{Trex1}$^{-\!/\!-}$}

\begin{document}

\trex\ good?

\trexA\ better?

\trexM\ good?

\trexMM\ better?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should not surround each symbol with `$` . Use `$` to enter or leave inline math, so surround the entire expression. `\num` isn't a standard command it isn't clear what you intend it to do. (The `siunitix` package has a command of that name but unrelated to this I think) so I think you want

```
some text  $\mathit{Trex1}^{-/-}$ some more text
```

but it is hard to be sure as you provided little context about the intended use here.